# Any interesting properties of Fermat's Last Theorem Surfaces?

Tags: number-theory, 3d, surfaces

I wonder if there are any interesting geometric
(as opposed to number-theoretic) properties of what might be called
*Fermat's Last Theorem surfaces*, i.e.,
$x^d + y^d = z^d$. Below are the surfaces for $d=2,4,6$.

---

[image: FermatEven]

They seem rather tame...

Comment: Each one of their horizontal cross-sections (assuming *z* is the vertical dimension, as in the three figures you presented) is a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse). They are connected to the Gamma and Beta functions (see link). For rational values of the form $d=\dfrac1n$ in between $0$ and $1$, they are linked to factorials and binomial coefficients. The case $d=4$ is called a [squircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle).

Comment: @Lucian: Nice observations!

Comment: Given the mathematics involved in the proof of Fermat's last theorem, I thought from the title that the question might have been about [elliptic curves](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RealEllipticCurves/) or something.

Comment: @Lucian: If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each one of their horizontal cross-sections (with *z* being the vertical dimension, as in the $3$ figures you presented) is a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) (the case $d=4$ is called [squircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle)), and are connected to the famous [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [Beta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in terms of area. For rational values of the form $d=\dfrac1n$ , with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, they are linked to [factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) and [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).